# Transparency artifacts appearing on iOS

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Does anyone know why I'm getting these weird artifacts when I overlap 3d planes with textures on top of each other even if they are on different layers?
[image]

The smaller shapes are supposed to be hiding behind the big shape but what is happening is that the alpha channel cuts through the top shape.
I would like to add that this only happens on ios not on android.

The way I'm organising the layers is by stacking 3d planes on top of each other.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. The solution was to disable the "Use Depth Test" and "Write to Depth.." for all overlapping materials. After changing this everything worked as expected.

[image]